# How to list only empty directories using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I want to list down all the empty directories inside a S3 bucket using AWS CLI.

Does anyone know what can be query for this?

I tried running this:

```
aws s3 ls bucket_name/ --recursive
```

but it is returning the non empty folders as well. I only need the **empty folders** present inside the bucket.

Comment: AWS removes empty folders automatically so you can't do this.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207198/empty-folders-in-aws-s3 for details.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to understand is that **directories do not actually exist in Amazon S3**. Instead, the name (Key) of objects includes the **full path** of the object.

For example, you could upload a file to `invoices/january.pdf` and the `invoices` directory would magically appear. If the object was then deleted, the directory would simply disappear (because it did not actually exist).

If you click the **Create folder** button in the Amazon S3 management console, it will create a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. This causes the folder to 'appear', but the folder/directory doesn't actually exist.

As to **how to list only empty folders**, you would need to:

- List the entire bucket
- Loop through the list and figure out which paths have no objects within the path -- this is best done in a programming language, such as Python

The bottom line is **you'll need to write a program** to do this. There is no simple solution.